# github actions の中から元のレポジトリへタグを push できますか？

Tags: github-actions

github action でできる限り OSS のルーチンを自動化しようと思うと、タグを元のレポジトリに push したくなります。

## 質問

- github action にて、元レポジトリへのタグの push はどうやったらできるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[Tagを打ってくれるActionはいくらか存在](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=tag)するようですので、これらを使えば実現できるでしょうか。

公式の機能で実装するには、[`github-script`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-script)を使い、[`createTag()`](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v17#git-create-tag)を呼ぶことでしょうか。

```
uses: actions/github-script@0.9.0
with:
  github-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
  script: |
    github.git.createTag({
      owner: context.repo.owner,
      repo: context.repo.repo,
      tag: ...,
      message: ...,
      object: ...,
      type: ...
    })
```

（試したわけではありません。）